# PHP GD Library, rendering an image - saving the image or not (what is the most effective solution)?

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a PHP script that renders an image from another image using PHP GD Library. I need to know what is the most effective solution (what is the best way):

1.Render the image "on the fly" like this:

```
<img src="createImage.php=id=1" />
```

OR:

2.Render/create the image while uploading the first image, and then store it in a database?

```
<img src="$image" />
```

Please post a link to your source if you have any :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is faster to Render/create the image while uploading the first image, and store it NOT IN THE DATABASE (!!!), **but in the filesystem**!!! Refrain from using BLOBs for this purpose, it is unnecessary overhead. Moreover, files are much easier to backup than a huge database full of blobs.

So the second possibility is right, but use the filesystem. I'd call this technique "caching".

Comment: How do i save files in the filesystem, i dont understand? If i'd go for 2 i would create the image, and save the filename in the database in row "image_thumb" for example

Comment: @2by, you can use e.g. the `imagejpeg()` function (or whatever newer equivalent ...) which saves the jpg as file. In db you just store its name (possibly like <id>.jpg) and that's it.

Comment: That is what i meant with the 2. option :)

Answer (score 1):

2 - Is the better option. You minimize server resource consumption, but as `Tomas` pointed out store it in a directory rather than in the database, its easier and faster to access.

Comment: @2by Unfortunately, no :P. But here http://www.google.com.ng/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=saving+image+to+database+or+filesystem